# Getting rid of redundant method definitions

Tags: javascript, function, oop, optimization

There are four methods corresponding for each HTTP request methods which I use for route building.

The scheme for each method is:

```
RouteBuilder.prototype.>>METHOD<< = function (params, callback) {
    if(typeof params === "function") {
        callback = params;
        router.>>METHOD<<(this._path, callback);
        return;
    }

    var subRoute = params.subRoute || "";
    var url = this._path + subRoute;
    if(params.auth !== undefined) {
        router.>>METHOD<<(url, Auth.authenticate(params.auth, { session: false }), callback);
    } else {
        router.>>METHOD<<(url, callback);
    }
};
```

As you probably suspect the methods' names are: get, post, put and delete.
Currently I've got four almost same method definitions, I'm looking for more elegant approach.

I thought about creating an array with method names and map the methods to it, using key parameter, but creating functions in loop doesn't seem to be a good idea. Also I need for these methods to be compatible with JSDoc.

Comment: Yes, if you want to create lots of similar functions, create them in a loop. There's nothing wrong with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'll post an answer since you've already done 99% of the work. The code you posted in your question is pretty darn close to the generic solution you're looking for:

```
RouteBuilder.prototype.route = function (method, params, callback) {
    if(typeof params === "function") {
        callback = params;
        router[method](this._path, callback);
        return;
    }

    var subRoute = params.subRoute || "";
    var url = this._path + subRoute;
    if(params.auth !== undefined) {
        router[method](url, Auth.authenticate(params.auth, { session: false }), callback);
    } else {
        router[method](url, callback);
    }
};

RouteBuilder.prototype.get = function(params, callback) {
    this.route("get", params, callback);
};

RouteBuilder.prototype.put  = function(params, callback) {
    this.route("put", params, callback);
};

RouteBuilder.prototype.post = function(params, callback) {
    this.route("post", params, callback);
};

RouteBuilder.prototype.del = function(params, callback) {
    this.route("del", params, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> I thought about creating an array with method names and map the methods to it, using key parameter, but creating functions in loop doesn't seem to be a good idea.

There is nothing wrong with that approach, it's very simple and effective:

```
['get', 'post', 'put', 'delete'].forEach(function(METHOD) {
    RouteBuilder.prototype[METHOD] = function (params, callback) {
        if(typeof params === "function") {
            callback = params;
            router[METHOD](this._path, callback);
            return;
        }

        var subRoute = params.subRoute || "";
        var url = this._path + subRoute;
        if(params.auth !== undefined) {
            router[METHOD](url, Auth.authenticate(params.auth, { session: false }), callback);
        } else {
            router[METHOD](url, callback);
        }
    };
});
```